# Out of memory on Samsung Galaxy series

Tags: android, genymotion, samsung-galaxy

I have a welcome layout that is my first layout when starting the app. I can run the project successfully in other devices and in the emulator from Android Studio.

But when I try to run on the Genymotion emulator with Samsung Galaxy series, it show the error

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                                          Process: com.example.huaweb_system.taiwanuniversityhome, PID: 2325                                                                                            java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 157286412 byte allocation with 6136736 free bytes and 87MB until OOM

and marks this code

```
at com.example.huaweb_system.taiwanuniversityhome.StartSplash.onCreate(StartSplash.java:49)
```

Here is my welcome layout class:

```
public class StartSplash extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageView imageStartSplash;
    private static final int GOTO_MAIN_ACTIVITY = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start_splash);//show error on this line

        handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(GOTO_MAIN_ACTIVITY, 4000);
        //my image is 1280*1920.png
        imageStartSplash = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageStartSplash);
        //fade out image
        AlphaAnimation alpha = new AlphaAnimation(1.0F, 0.0F);
        alpha.setDuration(4000);
        alpha.setFillAfter(true);
        imageStartSplash.setAnimation(alpha);

    }

    //delay setting
    private Handler handler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                case GOTO_MAIN_ACTIVITY:
                    Intent intent = new Intent(StartSplash.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

I really don't know why? I try to remove them like:

```
//imageStartSplash = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageStartSplash);
//fade out image
//AlphaAnimation alpha = new AlphaAnimation(1.0F, 0.0F);
//alpha.setDuration(4000);
//alpha.setFillAfter(true);
//imageStartSplash.setAnimation(alpha);
```

It still shows the error... why does that happen?

Here is my layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/activity_start_splash"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.example.user.taiwandigestionsociety_v11.StartSplash">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            //i find that if i change the image smaller is would be fine.
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/splash_screen_portrait_xxxhdpi_1280x1920"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:id="@+id/imageStartSplash" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Show your xml layout.

Comment: I just find that may be the issue is my image byte , now my question is how exactly the suggestion is set Image background on Samsumg Galaxy series ?

Comment: @user2234894 , i update my xml layout.

Comment: Try to just provide 1 image file and place it in 'drawable-nodpi' only? (Remember to remove your images from drawable-hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi etc)

Comment: Hey thanks for your responding , some one teach me fix the image lower than 6136736 bytes , i fix the issue now , thanks you !